# How to detect which part of page user is currently on, like on this page?

Tags: jquery, css, html, dreamweaver

I'm implementing a **left** navigation bar very similar to this one found on https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/partners/  ( please see the left bar )

( Please note , you must open this page with firefox/chrome, the page has completely different css for IE).

If you now use the scroll bar on the right and scroll down, the left navigation bar automatically detects that you are on a different page and updates itself accordingly.

I am not sure how to implement that, do I use a jquery plugin ? do I access some DOM property to update my left navigation bar based on where the user is right now? How do I go about this ?

Thanks

Comment: This is what you're looking for. http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy

Comment: Just wanted to post the same link xD Well, one comment to that link would be enough ;)

Comment: @AlexMorrise ... that looks super!!!! I think this is exactly what i needed! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use $(window).scroll() event to update the left nav bar

Comment: thx.yes thats' another option, although the scrollspy plugin is exactly what i needed.:)

Comment: if you have a page complex as mozilla's surely scrollspy would be great to save labor.